# How to handle login sessions in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How to handle login sessions in sencha touch?

i know one way to handle using localstorage we can do that. but i need to know if any other ways achieve this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use local storage by setting item to it and getting item.

It is better way to do that.